# Android unable to set image on imageview with surfaceview

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-camera, surfaceview

I have a camera preview surfaceview that I am trying to place an imageview over, the image shows up fine with a resource image but if I use a bitmap (acquired from taking a picture using setImageBitmap or setImageDrawable - with a BitmapDrawable) the image does not show up. I have confirmed the bitmap is fine in the debugger. I have included the snippet of how I am setting it. If I don't call startPreview I can confirm the image is there as expected.

```
if (bitmap != null) {
            ImageView beforeImageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

            preview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

            beforeImageView.setImageDrawable(d);
            beforeImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            preview.addView(beforeImageView, 1);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        }
```

Where mCamera is the Camera object and this is being called from the onPostExecute of an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to trying to load too large of a bitmap, it was quietly throwing a notice in the log as it was unable to create a texture. Reducing the bitmap's size solved the issue.